# How to remove all items of a specific type on the server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My goal is to remove all existing Elytras from our server (only on the overworld, but not much of a problem otherwise, since we can just respawn the end).

I read about the command `/kill @e[type=Item]` on reddit. It did not work for me somehow. I tried it using: `/kill @e[type=elytra]` and got the message "Selector '@e[type=minecraft:elytra]' found nothing. Entity type type 'minecraft:elytra' is invalid". I took one out of the chest, threw it on the ground, but I get the same message.

The entity type cannot be invalid IMHO, since `/give <playername> elytra` works.

Comment: The entity type for dropped items is always `item`. `elytra` is an item name but not an entity type. `/kill @e[type=Item]` should remove all dropped items, but only from chunks that are loaded. Are you wanting to remove the item from chests and unloaded chunks too?

Comment: @SirBenet I'm looking for a way to remove all items, also those stored in chests and player inventories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands can't target entities in unloaded chunks, and are generally bad at editing the contents of containers. To do what you want to do, you will need to use an external tool.

Here's how to do it with [MCEdit Unified](http://www.mcedit-unified.net/):

1. Double click on any chest containing an elytra to bring up the chest GUI:

[image: MCedit Chest GUI]

2. Select the elytra in the item list
3. Press <kbd>Delete All Instances Of This Item From World</kbd>
4. You'll get a warning message telling you what you're about to do, to which you should press <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image: Warning message]

5. After it's done deleting the item (may take a while) save and exit.

This should only affect the current dimension you're in on MCEdit, so you will not need to regenerate the end.

Comment: I will check this out probably this evening and report back. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry that it took so long. I tried it and it worked! The only problem is: All animals on the world were removed. This is not a big deal though, since we can just spawn them in creative mode, but it was a bit annoying when I noticed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An item is always `@e[type=item]`, whether its a stone block or a sapling or a bone or an elytra.
to achieve what you're trying to do, you'd have to tag all items that actually are elyras and kill those.

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=item] add isElytra {Item:{id:"minecraft:elytra",Count:1b}}
/kill @e[type=item,tag=isElytra]
```

the problem with this is though, that it will only kill all *items* that are *lying around*, *not* in chests or player inventorys, and only in *loaded chunks*, so not everywhere on the server. if that is a problem for you, you should try the [solution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/295662/172377) of @SirBenet

Comment: That doesn't help me, but it may help someone else who gets here over google. Thank you :)

Comment: Also, in 1.13+ you can use the `nbt=` selector to select those items that are elytra. `/kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:elytra"}}]`